# Issues with "npm install" -- Laravel-mix

Tags: laravel

I am trying to install NPM on my build that is using laravel, composer, and jigsaw tightenco.

However, when i run the npm install command, I get the following WARN.

npm WARN laravel-mix-purgecss@3.0.0 requires a peer of laravel-mix@^2.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I've tried running npm install laravel-mix, and a bunch of other things but nothing seems to work... What exactly does this all mean?

Here's my error log:

```
7554 silly saveTree   `-- yargs-parser@2.4.1
7555 warn notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"13.11.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
7556 warn notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
7557 verbose notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
7557 verbose notsup Required: {"node":"<8.10.0"}
7557 verbose notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.5","node":"13.11.0"}
7558 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
7559 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
7560 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
7560 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
7560 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
7560 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
7561 warn laravel-mix-purgecss@3.0.0 requires a peer of laravel-mix@^2.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
7562 verbose stack Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, read
7562 verbose stack     at C:\Users\goldb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:245:7
7562 verbose stack     at C:\Users\goldb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
7562 verbose stack     at callback (C:\Users\goldb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
7562 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:172:5)
7563 verbose cwd H:\MG_personal_sites\learn-vue-js
7564 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
7565 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\goldb\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "laravel-mix"
7566 verbose node v13.11.0
7567 verbose npm  v6.14.5
7568 error code EINVAL
7569 error EINVAL: invalid argument, read
7570 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: `watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0` seems to require node versions lower than 8.10

Comment: I think overall you have a version confusion going on here. `laravel-mix-purgecss` is not a default part of laravel mix, so it should not be installed in the first place. Not sure where `watchpack-chokidar2` is coming from either . I suggest you take the [package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json) that comes with laravel by default and base yours on that and then run `npm install`